# Find a value in range + loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need my macro to Look at a cell in my range, Find that value in the a different WS and paste a value on to that's next to the value i'm looking for (my original WS). do this again and again to the values in the range.

now it all works but for some reason the value is stuck on the first search and wont look for other values in the original range.
here is my code, and the pictures should help.

```
Sub Macro1()
```

'
'now im gonna match the "UDD" TO THE "S/O"

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("c17").Select

   Dim Searchkey As Range, cell As Range
   Set Searchkey = Range("c17:c160")

For Each cell In Searchkey
Sheets("data").Activate
Cells.Find(What:=Searchkey, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Next cell
```

End Sub

why is my macro stuck on "84225" and not looping to the other S/O?

Thank you[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stuck"? Error message? Does your loop work?

Comment: as in...it keeps on looking for "84225" and isn't moving on to "85511" and then "85370" and so on

Comment: its still searching only for "84225" and ignoring other S/Os :/

Comment: its working now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub mac1()


Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("c17").Select


Dim srch As Range, cell As Variant
Set srch = Range("c17:c160")

For Each cell In srch
Sheets("data").Activate

    Cells.Find(What:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Next cell
```

End Sub

this is working!
thank you all

Answer (score 0):

On each loop you're searching for the whole range of `SearchKey` and not just `Cell` so I'm guessing it's always using the first cell in SearchKey as your search criteria.

You're also searching in the formula rather than the values, and looking for a part match which may return incorrect results (part match on 20 would return a find in 20, 201, 11120001, etc).

Not qualifying your sheet names and using Activate probably isn't helping much either.

Try this code:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim SrcSht As Worksheet, TgtSht As Worksheet
    Dim SearchKey As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim FoundValue As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set SrcSht = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set TgtSht = .Worksheets("Data")
    End With

    Set SearchKey = SrcSht.Range("C17:C21")
    For Each Cell In SearchKey
        'Search column 3 (C) for your the value
        Set FoundValue = TgtSht.Columns(3).Find(What:=Cell, _
                                                After:=TgtSht.Columns(3).Cells(1, 1), _
                                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        'Only proceed if value found, otherwise an error will occur.
        If Not FoundValue Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Offset(, 1) = FoundValue.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
To test the code place the cursor within the procedure and press F8 to process each line in turn.  The `FoundValue` should contain a value each time it's executed.

To check this hover your cursor over the variable to see its value:

[image]

The row highlighted in yellow is the next line that will be executed.  If `FoundValue` is nothing then the following line isn't processed, if it's not nothing then the line is executed.

Comment: i used your code and now nothing is happening. think of it as if im "Ctrl F" for each value in my range and looking for it in the other Sheet ("data")

Comment: That's what the code does - Ctrl F on each value in `SearchKey`.  There's a couple of things that could be causing it:  Is `SearchKey` looking at the correct range (I changed it to `C17:C21` on `Sheet1` for testing).  Are the values you're searching for in column C on the `Data` sheet?  Are the numbers on both sheet formatted as numbers or text (as long as they're both the same it should work).  Trying stepping through the code using F8 - does `FoundValue` contain a value after the `Find` command if it never does then that's the bit that's failing so it just skips over the `Cell.Offset(` line.